# Cannot move out of shared reference of a recursive struct

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement Gale-Shapley algorithm in Rust and I need to declare a recursive struct like this:

```
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
struct Person {
    name: char,
    preference: Vec<Person>,
    pref_index: usize,
    candidates: Vec<Person>,
    partner: Option<Box<Person>>, // using Box makes it easier to declare recursive structs
}

impl Person {
    fn propose_to_next(&mut self) {
        /* propose to next most preferred person */

        if self.pref_index >= self.preference.len() {
            ()
        }

        let person = self.preference[self.pref_index];
        self.candidates.push(person);

        self.pref_index += 1;
    }

    fn pick_preferred(&mut self) {
        /* pick the next more preferred partner or stay with the current one */

        for person in &self.preference {
            let p = Some(Box::new(*person));

            if p == self.partner {
                break;
            } else if self.candidates.contains(&person) {
                self.partner = p;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this gives me the error

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `std::vec::Vec<Person>`
  --> src/lib.rs:18:22
   |
18 |         let person = self.preference[self.pref_index];
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                      |
   |                      move occurs because value has type `Person`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                      help: consider borrowing here: `&self.preference[self.pref_index]`

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `*person` which is behind a shared reference
  --> src/lib.rs:29:35
   |
29 |             let p = Some(Box::new(*person));
   |                                   ^^^^^^^ move occurs because `*person` has type `Person`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

How do I fix this? Is my approach flawed? I tried a non OO approach using just vectors and hashmaps but it is ugly since I will have to pass in everything in every function.

Comment: Hi @Ishaan, what line does your error occur at? Could you post the full error message?
Could you also post a working example that people could compile and run on their own (e.g., fix the candidates to a member of the struct)?

Your struct doesn't implement the Copy trait  as suggested by the compiler. I suspect you'll have to  implement that manually for `self.partner = p` to work

Comment: Feel free to post a link to a functional example here: https://play.rust-lang.org/

Comment: [Link to Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c02ccaa69420485ad92aecc7f7769a15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably do it in your case.
Notice how the struct doesn't have ownership of either the elements of the `preference` vector or the partner but just holds a (static for simplicitly) reference to them.

Notice also that you have to implement the `PartialEq` trait for this to work

```
use std::vec::Vec;

struct Person {
    name: char,
    preference: Vec<&'static Person>,
    partner: Option<&'static Person>
}

impl Person {
    fn pick_preferred(&mut self, candidates: &Vec<Person>) {
        for person in &self.preference {
            if candidates.contains(&person) {
                self.partner = Some(person);
            }
        }
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Person {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.name == other.name
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let candidates: Vec<Person>;
    let p: Person;
    ....
}
```

Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4b1fab2d4f2188c8d50fd21762ad126c